# Serial input through Parallel port

Tags: c#

Can any ony kindly explain that how we can take serial data as input from parallel port using c#.
Or the serial communication through parallel port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really wouldn't transmit your data this way as you are heading for a world of pain. Far better to use a serial to USB IC such as the excellent ones made by [FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/). In simple terms these take your TTL serial data send it via USB. Thanks to the FTDI drivers the data appears as a virtual serial port which your program can read from in the usual way.

Hope this helps.

Ian

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question if you are looking for a software or hardware solution. AN external serial to paralell converter (hardware) provides the simpliest solution.

If you are looking for a software only solution, you want to do "[bit banging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit-banging)". Unfortunately this requires precise timing, something which may be extremely difficult in managed code. This sort of program is typically implimented in a lower level language such as assembler or C where one has direct access to the hardware. Here is another [article](http://www.ganssle.com/articles/auart.htm) specifically addressing the use of the paralell port for serial communications.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're doing something wrong. If you need serial input, why not use the serial port? I believe that the [RS232](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) standard is widely supported. The parallel port is for parallel data transfers.